# Bring VS Code to the foreground when breaking in the debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Regular Visual studio has this nice feature. I don't think it is available in VS Code.
[image]

When a breakpoint hits you can jump right to bebugging (pressing f5,f10 etc) without having to click on the IDE first.  I love this feature.  Does anyone know if VS Code supports this as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supposed to focus the vscode window.  There is this setting:

> Debug : Focus Window on Break

which is enabled by default.  But see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80441 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/77213 it looks there are issues.

It doesn't work for me either on Win10.  I added my example to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105913.  You may want to do the same.

Comment: Yeah, Broken for me on window 10 :(